# Search application to handle up to 40 million full-text documents using Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene, indexing, loading

My current search application is using lucene for indexing process. And if any documents are change, I believe, we can start re-indexing at the beginning. Is this Correct?

So, if yes, then all documents have to re-indexed each time with new ones are added which will be not appropriate with very large number of content about 40 million full-text documents.

That's why I am specifically concerned that, using Lucene, Is there any way to only index documents that have changed so that to avoid the full re-indexing.

Appreciated for possible suggestions...

Thanking you........

Answer (score 0):

You only need to reindex changed documents, there is no need to reindex everything. `IndexWriter` has `deleteDocuments` which can remove documents by query or term. Then, you can reinsert the changed document with `addDocument` and `commit` to make this appear atomic.

Also bear in mind that Lucene is just a library and has no idea what kind of external entities are passed for indexing and how/when they change - you, as a developer, are responsible for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful response.

Actually, our search applicaton have usually followed with preliminary 3 consecutive processes,
1. Fetching (fetches relevant content)
2. Loading (Store appropriate data onto databases)
3. Indexing (take necessary attributes like doc_id, doc_obj, abstract_obj, fulltext_obj from already stored data from database (from step 2) for indexing.

So, our senario for indexing are totally based on data presence on database table while loading. So in this case, Is there any way to only index documents that have changed so that to avoid the full re-indexing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The usual practice is to provide these sort of details in the question itself. It is probably best if you edit your question with the data you have commented above. With regards to your comment, my answer still holds - regardless where the data is coming from, you only need to reindex what's changed and database is no exception. Just remove the outdated Lucene document and reinsert it, depending on your database-to-Lucene mapping logic.